# java spring boot application break down unexcept

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I just run jar application on the server,but application break down unexcept frequently,maybe the computer memory cause the problem, i am new guy for jvm problem,could someone answer me ? thanks a lot.

this is [hs_err_pid.log](https://www.zybuluo.com/931876502/note/1532236)

Comment: Update JDK. You are you using a way too old JDK 8u11 which is known to have critical JVM bugs.

Comment: JVM attempted to access memory it was not allowed access to which resulted in a crash.

Comment: thanks for answer，i‘ll hava a try with new version jdk